# Would it be worthwhile to support UART for a serial 'plug-n-play' interface? Or would it be a waste of time?

Tags: i2c, spi, uart

I'm currently working on a project where I'm designing a central circuit board that will feature mini plugin circuitboards. The communication between the main circuit board and the plugin circuitboards will be serial. I'm attempting to create a general interface such that the main circuit board can support SPI and I2C communications. I have a somewhat subjective question in need of a practical answer:

Would it be worth while to also support UART? Or would this be a waste of time?

I'll give a little more information regarding my application. The mini plugin boards will typically feature small ICs. I doubt that I would ever try to communicate with a PC with this interface.

Now, when I've been looking at some ICs that could potentially be featured on one of these plugin boards (i.e. an accelerometer), Digikey and Mouser really only list serial ICs with SPI and I2C interfaces. I'm having a difficult time finding any chips that feature UART. Thus bringing me to the question, should I even try to support UART on this serial interface I designing?

I realize this is a subjective question, however, I'm somewhat confused as to what typical applications UART is used for. As it doesn't appear to be used for IC-IC communications. Instead, the only real application I've been exposed to is it being used for flashing microcontrollers and communicating with PC peripherals.

So another question - where does the separation between SPI/I2C and UART come into play? Is SPI/I2C typically used for inter IC communications, and UART is reserved for longer distances because its more robust? Also, I'm well versed in the technical differences between SPI/I2C/UART, however, I'm not well versed in typical applications in which you should use one over the other.

Comment: This question isn't really one that fits the model of this site.  It has tended to be true that slave-side asynchronous interfaces like a UART are most commonly found on stored-program devices like MCUs (not to mention "real computers") while slave-side synchronous interfaces like I2C and SPI are more commonly found on dedicated function chips and simple CPLD/FPGA/ASIC custom logic, but there are counterexamples in both directions.  Only you can really decide what meets your needs.

Comment: Although you only mention ICs, if you intend to allow small plug in modules, things like GPS and wifi (e.g. ESP8266) tend to talk via UART.

Comment: Note that SPI and I2C are multidrop buses, i.e. on the same bus there can coexist many ICs, whereas UART is a point-to-point protocol, so you cannot attach multiple transmitters on the same UART "bus".

Comment: @LorenzoDonati - That is not really true, multi-drop asynchronous serial bus schemes have long been in use.  People may be most familiar with them in the form of RS485 & RS422, but you can do it with logic-level UARTs too, as long as you control the software on both ends and can tristate the transmit pins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Interesting! I didn't know you could do that with standard UARTs found in MCUs. So I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to support a UART. Almost all MCUs have a UART, and as @tcrosley said, many comm devices have UART interfaces.

I've done similar designs where I've added provisions for daughter-boards on servo controllers without knowing what they might end up being. It's not always easy to plan ahead. I recently added Bluetooth to a servo controller as a daughter-board, using the UART interface, so I was lucky that I had the UART pinned-out.

What @tcrosley says about "plug-and-play" is very true. Almost no interface that would be appropriate for a daughter-board lends itself to "plug-and-play". But since you likely have control over the creation of the daughter-boards, there are simple solutions.

My favorite solution is based on the fact that almost all the MCUs have an ADC. I dedicate one pin on the daughter-board interface for "board-detect". I wire that pin to an ADC channel that has a pull-up resistor. Each different daughter-board has a different value resistor assigned, and wired as a pull-down. The resulting voltage divider delivers a "signature" to the MCU.

The MCU reads the ADC on power-up, and then knows which daughter-board is attached (if any). Of course, the MCU would need firmware for each different board, but that would almost always be the case.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of "plug and play" is that the host can "discover" what type of peripheral is connected.  Plug and play can most easily be done on a per card basis; it is much harder to do it on an individual device basis as explained below.

Both I2C and SPI are used for most serial interfaces to ICs, with UART a distance third. The main alternative is a parallel interface, which you have ruled out.  I'll discuss the merits of each serial interface below.

Both SPI and I2C are designed to be implemented locally within a board or across multiple boards, like you are planning; they are typically not made available as an external interface.  UARTs are the same, unless they have a level converter chip to convert the UART's logic level signals to RS-232 counterparts, in which case they are good for a couple hundred feet.

Most modern microcontrollers may provide for a couple of I2C interfaces, maybe 4 SPI interfaces, and 4 or more UARTs.  You usually can't use all at once due to pin limitations.

#### Card-based addressing

The easiest way to distinguish between different interfaces is to do it on a board level, using card-based addressing.  This can be either digital or analog.  Four example three digital lines could be used to distinguish between eight card types.  An analog interface, requiring only one line, using a top voltage of 3v in a 3.3V system could support twelve cards "addresses" using 0.25V differences for each card.  You would need a table, based on the "card ID", which would tell you the types and number of serial interfaces on each card.

I have used the latter scheme to identify various versions of a PCB to a microcontroller, to allow it to use a common set of firmware across many different hardware versions.

#### I2C

I2C has the advantage of requiring only two lines, clock and data.  Addressing is built into the protocol.  If more than one chip of the same type is needed on the same I2C bus, then the chips usually have strappable address pins, such as A0-A2 will would provide for eight identical chips.

I2C is spec'ed for 100kHz, 400kHz and, more recently, 1 to 5MHz. As a result, I2C is typically used for slower interfaces, such as EEPROMs and NVRAMs containing user settings or configuration data, low-speed DACs and ADCs, small displays, sensors,  and real-time clocks.

I2C alone does not lend itself to a plug and play interface, since each I2C device has a unique address and must be queried.  You would need to have a list of all the possible I2C interfaces that can exist on the slave PCBs, and go through the list and try each one, and see which ones reply.

#### SPI

SPI interfaces require the most lines; a minimum of four lines for one chip; clock, input and output data lines, and a chip select to distinguish between chips.  Additional SPI chips must have their own chip selects.  So a board with three SPI chips would require 6 lines.  SPI is the fastest of these three types, going up to 50MHz.

SPI is typically used for faster interfaces such as high-speed DACs and ADCs, large displays, larger memory chips, and SD cards.

If one was to allow different types of slave PCBs, each supporting a number of chip selects, then again the host would need to have some sort of table of what devices can be selected by each chip select line.

#### UARTs

Devices with UART interfaces tend to be modems, such as cellular, Bluetooth and the like, often with "AT command" command interfaces like the old Hayes telephone modems of the 1980's and 90's.  UARTs would have to be treated the same way as SPI, since they don't have any addresses associated with them.  So one could issue a simple AT command (e.g. just AT/cr/lf) and see if it responds, and then issue unique commands for each possible device to determine its type.

(Another common use for UARTs, either intra-board or inter-board, is for two microcontrollers talking to each other.)

Like I2C, UARTs only require a minimum of two lines (Tx and Rx).  There are additional control lines (RTS and CTS for example), which, if you are going to be implementing a UART interface, would probably be worthwhile bringing out.  If they are not needed for UART interface, they could be used as general purpose I/O (GPIO) lines.

A difficulty with UART interfaces is they can be using one of several baud rates; 115200 is most common but I have seen devices using 9600, 19200 and 57600 in addition to 15.2K.  So if one got a garbage response using 115.2, you can try one of the lower baud rates.

UART interfaces compete with I2C in terms of speed; for a long time they were limited to 115.2K but now they can go up to a couple MHz.

Unless you plan on supporting boards that have wireless modems, it may not be worthwhile providing a UART interface.

Comment: First, you fail to answer the question.  Next, every point you try to make here has an obvious workaround or counterexample.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I have updated my answer to indicate the merits of each type of interface.

Comment: The only use you can think of for a UART is a wireless modem?   There is a reason questions like this aren't a fit for this site, and encouraging responses which lack perspective may have something to do with it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I said "tend do be modems".  In my 40 years of designing embedded system (I designed a mutiple-8080 system in 1976), they is the most common usage I have seen for intra-board and inter-board use.  The next most common use is perhaps two microcontrollers talking to each other, which I added to my answer.

Comment: DMX is a UART interface MIDI is too IIRC, both are external interfaces though,  I suppose a I2C or SPI  UART could be added if a UART is needed. eg: SC16IS750